# VB Script does not recognize the actual parameter

Tags: scripting, vbscript, scripting-language

I've two VB Scripts. Say **First.vbs** and **Second.vbs**.

**Frist.vbs** calls **Second.vbs** each time some action/event happens.

I am trying to send two parameters from **Frist.vbs** to **Second.vbs** using the following code:

Contents of **First.vbs**:

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
param1 = "Welcome"
param2 = "Gokul Nath"
objShell.Run "Second.vbs" & " " & param1 & " " & param2
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Contents of **Second.vbs**:

```
param1= Wscript.Arguments.Item(0)
param2 = Wscript.Arguments.Item(1)
WScript.Echo(param1)
WScript.Echo(param2)
```

I'm getting the following Echo messages:

```
Welcome - Which is correct, since I've passed "Welcome" from First.vbs
Gokul - Which is WRONG, since I've passed "Gokul Nath" from First.vbs
```

This issue occurs, since each space is considered as end of a parameter.

I am new to scripting, can anyone give some suggestion/reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `param2` contains a space and you didn't put the parameter between double quotes. Because of that your `Run` command-line effectively has 3 arguments:

- Welcome
- Gokul
- Nath

To avoid that add double quotes around your second argument:

```
objShell.Run "Second.vbs" & " " & param1 & " """ & param2 & """"
```

Better yet, quote *all* arguments and use a quoting function so you don't drown in double quotes:

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

objShell.Run "Second.vbs" & " " & qq(param1) & " " & qq(param2)
```

Comment: Hi Wiechers, can you please help me out with this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516311/display-a-drop-down-combo-box-in-vb-script