# Display a drop-down/combo box in VB Script

Tags: scripting, vbscript, scripting-language

I'm trying to create a drop-down/combo box in VB Script. As per my understanding we need to create an instance for Internet Explorer and create a drop-down/combo box, something like this:

```
  set oIE = createObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  with oIE
    .Navigate "about:blank"
    Do until .ReadyState = 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
    set oDoc = .document
    .Visible = true
  end with

  with oDoc
    .open
    .writeln "<html><head><title>ComboBox Example</title></head>"
    .writeln "<body scroll=no><object "
    .writeln "classid=clsid:8BD21D30-EC42-11CE-9E0D-00AA006002F3"
    .writeln "id=ComboBox1 width=400></object><p>"
    .writeln "</body></html>"
    .close
    Do until .ReadyState = "complete" : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
    set oComboBox1 = .all.ComboBox1

  end with

  with oComboBox1
    .List = Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")
    .AutoWordSelect = true
    .focus
  end with
  oDoc.parentWindow.opener = "Me"

  bClosing = false

  on error resume next
  do until bclosing: wsh.sleep 100 : loop
  oIE.quit

  sub Closing : bClosing = True : end sub
```

Is it possible to create an dorp-down/combo box without using IE, similar to Message Box or Input Box?

Comment: [worth a try](http://www.veretennikov.org/WSO/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite sure many users here will glad to answer on this question, and their reply may hold varied details, but for sure the answer w'd been the same - No. At least not with pure `VBScript` and without programming your own `ActiveX` component, which then to instantinate with `CreateObject` inside your `.vbs` script.

But if you looking for alternative then may consider [HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as an option for your own custom GUI.