# Convert String to Path For Run Command VBScript

Tags: vbscript

```
WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files\Target.exe"" -s"
```

In command above, I want to use a string instead of the path, but it is not working!

```
Directory = "C:\Program Files\Target.exe"
WshShell.Run """Directory"" -s"
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Chr(34)` might make things clearer.

```
Directory = "C:\Program Files\Target.exe"
WshShell.Run Chr(34) & Directory & Chr(34) & " -s"
```

Otherwise, the syntax you're looking for gets a bit complicated:

```
WshShell.Run """" & Directory & """ -s"
```

If you need to use a quote character within a string literal, it must be doubled.
And if you need to include a VBScript variable, it should be concatenated (`&`).

Comment: Arguably the best way of handling this is to wrap it in a [quoting function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15297245/1630171).